# How to stop Chrome New Tab from opening an infinite number of tabs?

Tags: google-chrome

I just upgraded Google Chrome to version 34.  As part of opening a new tab, it asked in a dialog box whether `xdg-open` was OK.  I said yes and to remember the setting.  Now when I try to open a new tab, Chrome opens a new window about every 700 milliseconds.

Where can I find that setting (to use `xdg-open`) and turn it off?

That is, where can I set what happens to the `chrome-internal://newtab` URL?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see anything specific to 'new tab' settings, but at the very least you could go to chrome://settings/ and reset browser settings to default. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.